# Show that the sequence given by $x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{\sqrt {|x_n|}}{n^2}$ is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

[image]

My Try:

It is clear that $x_n$ is monotonically increasing. If we assume that the sequence converges to $a$ then $\displaystyle a=a+\frac{\sqrt{|a|}}{n^2}$. Hence $a=0$. So, I was going to prove that the sup of the sequence is $0$. But failed. Can somebody please help me to complete the proof

Comment: You can try and show that the difference of two successive terms is convergent i.e. lim x_n+1 - x_n.

Comment: You could try the ratio test.

Comment: You forgot to take the limit of the $n^2$.

Comment: @IntrepidTraveller - but does that complete the proof?

Comment: @Malin Probably fixing the errors is a good idea before trying to "complete" it...

Comment: @MALIN really you should show the limit of the difference  of successive terms goes to zero

Comment: It's ED's question, not mine. Showing that limit of difference of successive terms isn't strong enough to show that sequence is convergent, however.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$
x_{n+1} = (\sqrt{x_n}+\frac1{2n^2})^2-\frac1{4n^4} \lt (\sqrt{x_n}+\frac1{2n^2})^2
$$
so
$$
\sqrt{x_{n+1}} \lt \sqrt{x_n} + \frac1{2n^2}
$$
hence
$$
\sqrt{x_{n+1}}-\sqrt{x_1} \lt \frac12\sum_{k=1}^n \frac1{n^2} \lt \frac{\pi^2}{12}
$$

Comment: Excellent idea. I think the proof will be more accurate if you use $|x_{n+1}|$

Comment: yes, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 4):

If your argument were correct it would show that the sequence *diverges* if $x_1>0$, because in that case the sup certainly can't be $0$. But your argument isn't correct. If you assume that $x_n\to a$ and plug that into the recurrence you get just $a=a$, which doesn't tell you much about $a$. (You forgot that $n\to\infty$ as $n\to\infty$.)

It's true that the sequence is increasing. You're not asked to *find* the limit. So you just have to show the sequence is bounded.

If $x_n<1$ for all $n$ then the sequence is bounded. Suppose not: There exists $N$ with $x_N\ge1$. Then $\sqrt{x_N}\le x_N$, so $$x_{N+1}\le\left(1+\frac1{N^2}\right)x_N.$$

Similarly for $x_{N+2}$ you get $$x_{N+2}\le\left(1+\frac1{N^2}\right)\left(1+\frac1{(N+1)^2}\right)x_N.$$And so on. You only need to show that $$\prod_{n=N}^\infty\left(1+\frac1{n^2}\right)<\infty.$$Read a little about infinite products, or take the logarithm, and you see this follows from $\sum\frac1{n^2}<\infty$.

Comment: $n\to \infty$ as $n \to \infty$. ;-)

Answer (score 4):

No, the limit is not $0$ in general.

Hint: 
$$x_n - x_1 = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} (x_{j+1} - x_j) = \sum_{j=1}^{n-1} \dfrac{\sqrt{|x_j|}}{j^2} $$
Find $M$ such that $|x_1| < M^2$ and $M \sum_{j=1}^\infty 1/j^2 < M^2 - x_1$, and show that
all $|x_j| \le M^2$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate the last step, it is not clear.

Comment: Given a suitable $M$, you can do the last step using induction and the first equation in my hint.